# How to connect swap chain and compositor

Tags: visual-c++, directx, c++-winrt

In my UWP application I am going to use Windows.UI.Composition which has a Compositor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor that abstracts access to hardware compositor in order to render Video and UI simultaneously with two separate render loops
For that I need to use a SwapChain for Composition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforcomposition
But I don't know and can't find suitable samples on how to connect the  Compositor with the respective swap chains for those 2 visual elements i.e. that one swapchain is for video's render target and the other is for UI's

Please help me understand the workflow in this case

Answer (score 0):

There is a repro for these samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples).